# Tailwind V3 causing TypeError: Cannot read property '500' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I recently tried to upgrade my project to tailwind css and I'm getting this error

[image: Console Error]

this is my tailwind config

```
 module.exports = {
      mode: "jit",
      purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      darkMode: "class", // or 'media' or 'class'
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            secondaryDark: "#171A1A",
            primaryDark: "#090A0A",
            neonOrange: "#FF9933",
            redditRed: "#FF5700",
            cardGradientPrimary: "#ff930f",
            cardGradientSecondary: "#fff95b",
          },
        },
      },
      variants: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
    };
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your error, but you should modify your config first. `mode: jit` is no longer required, use `content` instead of `purge`, and update `@tailwindcss/forms` to `0.4.0` or above. Also, delete `.next` and try rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks this helped I also had to update tailwind UI

Comment: Updating tailwind forms helper me

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I have the same issue after upgrade to tailwind v3 and fixed it by update @tailwindcss/forms to 0.4.0

Comment: Try adding v0.4.0-alpha.2 with this command:  npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms@next

Comment: it solves like a charm

Comment: Nice. Can confirm this works for forms 0.5.0 too.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

> ***npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms@next***

to update the plugins @tailwindcss/forms